# Unable to show status bar below slide menu as expected

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following code for slide menu to appear on the view:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(blurrView)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(sideMenuView)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { self.sideMenuView.frame.origin.x += UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.786}, completion: nil)
```

However this is seen as:

[image: output]

instead of expectation being

[image: this]

I am not able to understand how to come up with a solution for this. Please help me understand what I can do to get the expected result?

Edit: Even if your solution is very different from how I approached it, please share your views on how I should be able to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal
```

when adding blurrView